# Ruby extended hook with template method

Tags: ruby

I am trying to call a [template method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) within the [extended](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-i-extended) hook. My extended code look like this

```
module M
  def self.extended(mod)
    mod.template_method
  end

  def template_method
    raise 'Please implement me in the concrete class'
  end
end

class C1
  def self.template_method
    puts 'OK, implemented in C1'
  end
  extend M
end

class C2
  extend M
  def self.template_method
    puts 'OK, implemented in C2'
  end

end
```

The running result is available at [codepad](http://codepad.org/3W2iPxea). The code in C1 passed, but the the code in C2 triggered exception. The only difference in C1 and C2 is where the "extend" method was called. It seems that the "extened" hook does not recognize code defined after the "extend" call. I am wondering if there is any way to get around this.

Coming from c#, I am used to put all my ["using" detectives](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx) in the beginning of class. Does ruby's extend and include follow the same convention?

**Edit:**
  To reflect on @mudasobwa's comment, I have removed the "abstract method". The code can be found at http://codepad.org/3qvzan0m
  But the same problem exists, I do believe that the abstract method give me a chance to give more instructive message in stead of "method not found"

**Edit 2:** 
  What I wanted to achieve is to dynamically create test cases based on attributes of including class C
  The code snippet looks like

```
def self.extended(mod)
  methods = mod.expected_methods
  methods.each do |name|
   define_method("test_must_implement_#{name}") do
     assert_respond_to(@object, name)
   end 
 end
```

end

Hope this clarifies my motivation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**: The order matters. That said, the module is being evaluated right in the place it was mentioned:

```
module M
  def self.extended(mod)
    puts 'I AM BEING EXTENDED'
  end 
end

class C1
  puts 'I AM C1'
  extend M
end

class C2
  extend M
  puts 'I AM C2'
end

#⇒ I AM C1
#⇒ I AM BEING EXTENDED
#⇒ I AM BEING EXTENDED
#⇒ I AM C2
```

This is done on purpose, since you could rely on already included/extended stuff in the latter code:

```
module M
  def self.extended(mod)
    mod.foo = 'bar'
  end·
end 

class C2
  def self.foo= value
    @@foo = value
  end 
  extend M
  puts "Foo is: #{@@foo}"
end 

#⇒ Foo is: bar
```

**UPD** Answering to the update:

In general, `extended` callback is executed while the target class is not fully loaded. There is a trick on how to wait until it is initialized and execute everything on complete class (besides possible future monkeypatches, of course):

1. Declare a [`TracePoint`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/TracePoint.html) on target class initialization;
2. Wait until `:end` is reached;
3. Execute the code.

Putting this all together:

```
  def self.extended mod
    self.postpone_init mod
  end

  def self.postpone_init mod
    TracePoint.new(:end) do |tp|
      if tp.self == mod
        self.do_stuff
      else
        warn "TracePoint failed: #{tp}."
      end
      tp.disable
    end.enable
  end

  def self.do_stuff
    # HERE YOU GO
  end
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I realized that order matters. Is there any way to get round this? Or putting extend after method definition is a common practice so I don't have to worry?

Comment: The common workaround in ruby is to _never declare abstract interface methods_. We gotta used to [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing). There never is any profit of having this “must be defined” garbage in `M`. It violates DRY principle, bringing nothing on the table.

Comment: I have removed the abstract method. The new code is at http://codepad.org/3qvzan0m This might be better idiomatic ruby but my original problem still persist.

Comment: Why on the Earth you need to call this method _while a class is being extended_? It’s a claim to execute some stuff during object initialization. What might be a purpose? In the common scenario one would call smth like `self.foo if self.respond_to? :foo` after the objects are initialized. At the moment you are trying to call this method _the class definition is even incomplete_.

Comment: What I wanted to achieve is dynamically calling define_method to create tests base on certain attribute values from the including class "C".

Comment: Gotcha. This is a rare scenario, but I ran into the same problem last week. Then yes, whether you are free to put `extend M` whereever you want, just put it in the end and don’t worry. My quest was more complicated: the original class code was out of my reach. There is a hack for that, too: one should set a [`TracePoint`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/TracePoint.html) on the class being extended, wait until it’s initialization is ended and _just after that_ execute the patching code. Whether you are interested in the code snippet, just let me know.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74949/discussion-between-wei-ma-and-mudasobwa).